# Django 1.7 - SQL - Get data from One-To-Many relationship where relation may or may not exist

Tags: python, sql, django

I have the following database layout,

**User** ( has one ) **User_Profile**
**User_Profile** ( has none, one or many ) **World_Profile**
**World_Profile** ( has one ) **World**

I would like to select a list of all the **World** objects, and if a **world profile** exists for the logged in **User** the **World Profile** also.

The **World** table has the attribute is_public. I would like to get a list of all the **World** that have is_public = True, or where the user has a **World_Profile**.

I suspect it has something to do with the select_related term but I have not succeed yet. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Table Attributes**

User(username, first_name, last_name, email)
User_Profile(username(FK->User), info, foo, bar)
World_Profile(user_profile(FK), world(FK), character_name, gold)
World(world_name, game_speed, is_public, requires_subscription)

### SOLVED

```
filter_string = Q(is_public = True) | Q(worldprofile__user_profile__user=user)
World.objects.select_related().filter(filter_string)
```

Found the solution after a lot of trial and error, not sure why worldprofile doesn't need an underscore, I'll have to check that out. Thanks all.

Burhan Khalid has a better answer. 
    user = request.user
    user.user_profile.world_profile_set.filter(world__is_public=True)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy part is to get the currently logged in user, which is available in `request.user`. Since django offers reverse relations "for free", you can do the following:

```
user = request.user
user.user_profile.world_profile_set.filter(world__is_public=True)
```

Comment: Users may not have a World_Profile with a world. They should see all public worlds, and all worlds they have a profile with. So even if they don't have a profile with a public world it should still be returned. On the right track though, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

```
filter_string = Q(is_public = True) | Q(worldprofile__user_profile__user=user)
World.objects.select_related().filter(filter_string)
```

Found the solution after a lot of trial and error, not sure why worldprofile doesn't need an underscore, I'll have to check that out. Thanks all.